# python how to check if a nested list contain all None values

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this

```
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

How to efficiently check all elements are None?

I know how to do this for

```
lst = [None, None, None]

all(item is None for item in lst )
```

Comment: you need double loops: `print(all(item is None for ls in lst for item in ls))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, `all` would return `False` as soon as it would encounter a value different of `None`:

```
lst = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
all(item is None for sublist in lst for item in sublist)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def checkList(lstInput):
    for i in lst:
        for j in i:
            if j!=None:
                return False

    return True


lst=[[None,None,None],[None,None,None]]
print(checkList(lst))
```